# struct v4l2_capability device_params not reading

Tags: c

1st, opens file

```
fd = open("/dev/blackmagic/io0", O_RDWR);
```

2nd, this structure is zeroed

```
struct v4l2_capability device_params;
memset((void *)&device_params, 0, sizeof(device_params));
```

3rd,calls ioctl()

```
n = ioctl(fd, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, (void *)&device_params);
```

n is settled to 1002 and all device_params'fields are still empty.
How I must read this structure?

I expected that all structure's fields wiil be filled.

Comment: OT. Cast to `void*` in `memset()` is pointless

Comment: are you sure that `open` returned value >= 0?

Comment: value of `1002` is **very** strange because this `ioctl` can return only 0 or -1.

Comment: Yes, open() returns non-negative value. I'm not know how to explain 1002 value. This device has permission 666.

Comment: See [VIDIOC_QUERYCAP](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.9/media/uapi/v4l/vidioc-querycap.html#return-value). It is explicitly said that `ioctl` can return either 0 or -1. Maybe your V4L2 device driver is broken?

Comment: It seems that this device not support v42l.

Comment: This driver use own ioctl() functions and works throw bmio_client_ioctl(), but it is absent in the directory with driver source. There is object elf-file blackmagic_o.shipped with this function, its size is 2461880.